# SSRS 2008 Snapshotting Security

Tags: security, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm writing a report that will show data based on the `User!UserID` built into the SSRS infrastructure.  The data is sensitive to the user's department.

In addition to these department users, there will be admins that should be able to run for all departments, or have a report parameter to run for a specific department.

Ideally, I'd like to use SSRS snapshotting so that users can rerun a report they ran on a previous date.  It's important that a user can only view the snapshots he created for his department.

My questions are:
1.) Does SSRS snapshotting provide a mechanism to limit viewing snapshots by the user that created them?
2.) Will I need to write two reports, one for the admin and one for the department users?  I think I do since there isn't a way to secure report parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well for you first question:

- Does SSRS snapshotting provide a mechanism to limit viewing snapshots by the user that created them?

For each Snapshot, Under security tab, we can define the users/groups who can view the reports. This will manage what all user can see the report, now it will not have any control on "What data your report shows." I guess for that part we need to filter data based on UserId and then show in report. Hence it will ensure that right people will see the right report and right data inside it.

- Will I need to write two reports, one for the admin and one for the department users?

Well, theoretically its only the data which is different for a normal user and an admin user. So if while filtering/fetching the data you can identify which one is admin and which one is normal user, you can write appropriate query to return the appropriate data based on role.

If you can not determine the user role while filtering/fetching the data, then i guess you have to have two different reports.